# Have I proven Statement A implies Statement B?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

Below are two made-up statements that I will attempt to prove that A implies B:

---

Note: the discussion in the comments was related to when I had statement A as:

$∀x,y,z∈ℤ,x<y∧z≠x∧z≠y⇒0<f(x)<f(y)<f(z)$

---

Let $f:ℤ→ℤ$

Statement $A$

$∀x,y,z∈ℤ,x<y∧z≠x∧z≠y⇒0<f(x)∧0<f(y)∧0<f(z)$

Statement $B$

$∀a,b,c∈ℤ,a<b<c⇒f(a)+f(b)+f(c)>0$

Prove $A⇒B$

Assume $A$, Let $a,b,c∈ℤ$ and assume $a<b<c$

Since $a<b∧c≠a∧c≠b$, by hypothesis, this implies

$0<f(a)<f(b)<f(c)⇒f(a)+f(b)+f(c)>0$

There are probably easier ways of proving this but I just want to make sure I understand how implication works and all that jazz. Is this enough to prove $A$ implies $B$?

Comment: Well, since there does not exist a function $f$ satisfying statement $A$, we see that $A$ automatically implies $B$.

Comment: Do you mean that no function can satisfy the statement or that I just didn't define $f$?

Comment: I mean that there is no function satisfying the given statement. They key observation here is that $z$ has no restrictions in the definition. You can use this to prove that $f(0)<f(0)$, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, wouldn't a function like $e^x$ work?

Comment: But where did the $f(0)$ come from?

Comment: Set $(x,y,z)=(-2,-1,0)$ then set $(x,y,z)=(0,1,-2)$.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'll change the statement to something else.

Comment: I've changed the consequent of the first statement, hopefully a function will exist for that. Sorry about the mishap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your proof sketch doesn't quite work -- it depends on assuming $a<b<c$, and you cannot do that without loss of generality. In particular, if two of $a, b, c$ happen to be *equal* then there is no way you can rearrange them to achieve $a<b<c$.</s> *(As noted in the comments, this does work; I had misread $B$).*

What I would do instead is prove $\forall x:0 < f(x)$ by invoking $A$ with $y=x+1$ and $z=x+2$. Hopefully your underlying theory tells you enough about the integers to allow you to prove the assumptions in $A$ for that case, and then just throw away the two last thirds of the conclusion.

Then all you need to know is that the sum of three positive numbers is positive.

Comment: But aren't I allowed to assume the first statement and the hypothesis portion of the second statement?

Comment: @Spectacles: Whoops, sorry, you're right. I overlooked that assumption.